# After successful magisk flash, touch stopped working

Tags: android, root, fastboot

I flashed magisk patched img with fastboot on my moto e7 plus, but as I reboot the touch stopped . These are the commands I used:

`fastboot flash boot_a "location to img"`

`fastboot flash boot_b "location to img`

Then *fastboot reboot*.

I also read this post:

*https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/after-magisk-and-successful-flash-the-touch-screen-stopped-working.4427703/*

But unable to delete logical partition. The error is:

Deleting 'system_a' FAILED(remote: '')

fastboot: error: Command failed

I was trying to root the device, but the screen is stuck now, please help